# Error binding OffsetDateTime [operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone <= character varying]

Tags: jooq

We are trying to execute dml which deletes records based on ZonedDateTime. We are using following code but running into an error.

```
dsl.execute ("delete from fieldhistory where createddate <= ? and object = ?", beforeDate.toOffsetDateTime(), objName)
```

Where `beforeDate` is ZonedDateTime and `objectName` is string

We are getting following error from postgres.

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [delete from fieldhistory where createddate <= ? and object = ?]; ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone <= character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 56
    at org.jooq_3.13.1.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2751)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:385)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.execute(DefaultDSLContext.java:1144)
```

Questions is, how do we bind datetime value in Jooq?

Comment: Another way of running into this issue is when querying for an `OffsetDateTime` field. The error message in that case is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot decode value of type java.lang.String with OID 1184`. The fix is the same: set `bindOffsetDateTimeType` to `true` - see [Lukas Eder's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454732/147806), in particular [the linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9902).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historic reasons, jOOQ binds all JSR-310 times as strings, not as the relevant object type. This is because until recently, JDBC drivers did not support the JSR-310 types natively, and as such, using a string was not a bad default.

Unfortunately, this leads to type ambiguities, which you would not have if either:

- jOOQ didn't bind a string
- you were using the code generator and thus type safe DSL API methods

As a workaround, you can do a few things, including:

**Casting your bind variable explicitly**

```java
dsl.execute("delete from fieldhistory where createddate <= ?::timestamptz and object = ?",  
    beforeDate.toOffsetDateTime(), 
    objName)
```

**Using the DSL API**

```java
dsl.deleteFrom(FIELDHISTORY)
   .where(FIELDHISTORY.CREATEDDATE.lt(beforeDate.toOffsetDateTime()))
   .and(FIELDHISTORY.OBJECT.eq(objName))
   .execute();
```

**By writing your own binding**

You can write your own data type binding and attach that to generated code, or to your plain SQL query, in case of which you would be in control of how the bind variable is sent to the JDBC driver. See:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/

For example:

```java
DataType<OffsetDateTime> myType = SQLDataType.OFFSETDATETIME
                                             .asConvertedDataType(new MyBinding());
dsl.execute ("delete from fieldhistory where createddate <= {0} and object = {1}", 
    val(beforeDate.toOffsetDateTime(), myType), 
    val(objName))
```

There will be a fix in the future for this, so this won't be necessary anymore: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9902